# How to have access to the contents of folders cloned from different repositories in GitHub

Tags: git, github

So as of right now I'm in the 9th project of my traineeship at OpenClassrooms where I'm supposed to debug an application

I must clone the code for the Front-end and the Back-end of the app using the `git clone` command to get the code locally

I must also create a GitHub repo containing the code for both the Front-end and Back-end of the app

**So here's how the structure of the folders in my IDE looks like:**

[image: Structure of the]

(I have access to the content of these folders locally)

But I have a big issue, the code for the Front-end and the Back-end are from different GitHub repositories

So if I do:

```bash
git init

git add .

git commit -m "Initialising the Git repo"
```

GitBash will give me a warning saying that *"Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of

the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it."*

So in GitHub when I copy and paste the 3 commands to push the code from an existing Git repository, I do not have access to the code for the Front-end nor the Back-end of the app,

they have inside the folder icon an arrow pointing to the right :

[image]

Which is just as what the warning message from the GitBash Terminal said, **I cannot have access to the content of these folders because they're from another repository**

I tried using submodules but even after removing the codes from cache using:

```bash
git rm --cached bill-app/Billed-app-FR-Front

git rm --cached bill-app/Billed-app-FR-Back
```

And adding them back as submodules:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/LePhenix47/Lahouiti_Younes_9_06112022--Fix.git bill-app/Billed-app-FR-Front

git submodule add https://github.com/LePhenix47/Lahouiti_Younes_9_06112022--Fix.git bill-app/Billed-app-FR-Back
```

Does not solve the problem, I still do not have access to the content of these folders in GitHub

Currently I have no more ideas how to fix this, so if anybody could help me, I'd be very grateful

Also here's my repo: https://github.com/LePhenix47/Lahouiti_Younes_9_06112022--Fix

Comment: `git submodule add https://github.com/LePhenix47/Lahouiti_Younes_9_06112022--Fix.git bill-app/Billed-app-FR-Front` You have to add the URL of the `Billed-app-FR-Front` repo here, not the parent repo

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response,
I tried following your advice by adding the URL of the repo for both of the folders, but it simply redirects them to the repo where they were cloned from

Whereas I'd wish to not only have access to the content of these folders, but to also be able to modify their content in my repository

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to migrate the two repos into one, I would:

1. Make a top-level folder
2. Clone each into said top-level folder so they are siblings
3. Go into each and remove the .git folder.
4. Git init in the top-level folder adding the two projects as folders to the repo
5. commit and push

Step 3 basically removes the git repository status and functionality from the two original projects, removing any barriers from this new project tracking changes made to the folders.

If the goal is to maintain all three folders as repositories, then yes submodules are what you're looking for. I Would start from scratch and follow the documentation to a Tee that git provides.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Although I removed the .git folder on both folders, but despite that I still cannot have access to the content of these folders